# Is there any native tags or ways to build structurized lists in HTML?

Tags: html, list

I know, I can add &npsp; before items and use UL tag, but the dot still remain in one row.
How to make something I drawn on picture?

[image]

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to accomplish with `&nbsp`, you're doing it wrong. If you need to change visual styles, use CSS. Please describe *what* you're doing, without the *how*.

Comment: I want to make structurized list and said about &npsb; just as about one way of doing so, but I need another way,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested lists:

```
<ul>
    <li>Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1</li>
</ul>
```

This generates:

- Level 1

  - Level 2
  - Level 2
  - Level 2

    - Level 3
    - Level 3
    - Level 3
- Level 1

And so on.

Comment: Cool, I never though I can do that. Thank you.